# Unbind events from elements that are removed from the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom

I am having a discussion with a fellow developer about a problem we have with a web-app on iOS devices. It makes heavy use of events and jQuery. We currently have the problem that the app runs slow after being used for a certain amount of time.

My colleague suggests that the problem is that we bind event handlers on specific elements, e.g.

```
$("div#id123").on("click", function(....){....});
```

And, because we do this whenever we load new elements into the DOM, those event handlers eventually "pollute" the browser, making it slower.

As soon as a new element is loaded, the old ones are `$("div#id456").remove()`d from the DOM entirely, until they may be loaded again (completely new, no caching of any sort).

I cannot disprove him, but I am very sure that as soon as the old elements are removed, the event handlers are removed by the browser, too. After all: why should he keep them?

He suggest I rewrite all the handlers to have the form of

```
$(document).on("click", "div.commonclass", function(....){...});
```

to have the event handlers on document level, bound to the classes all the elements we deal with have in common.

This would mean some major rewriting for me which I'd like to avoid for something that, in my opinion, is not the root cause of our problem.

Is my assumption about events on removed elements correct and if so, how can I show my colleague that rewriting the event handlers is unnecessarily wasted work time?

Comment: Using `.remove()` removes any bound handler too. Using delegation as suggested would avoid to have many many handlers, depending how many elements. So i'd suggest you to try it too instead. Now your issue could come from somewhere else

Comment: use .detach() instead of remove() because .detach() act as remove temporary but event handlers didn't remove please try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that when you're using javascript specifically for iOS application, you need to be VERY careful when using jQuery due to the memeory overhead. I've frequently had to re-write jQuery heavy sections of javascript in native javascript to reduce the memeory footprint and ensure that it works effectively in the iOS environment. I've found the best way to debug in this case is to use the profiler in google chrome. Just answered a similar question, see here for more info: [Is there any possible danger of using "JQuery.on()" profusely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22961671/is-there-any-possible-danger-of-using-jquery-on-profusely/22962057#22962057)

When using a chrome profiler, take a heap snapshot, make your changes, then take another heap snapshot and compare. That way to can see the memeory impacts for your script changes.